# How do you create a sharepoint language templated site?

Tags: site-template, regional-settings

I notice that my company that I work for has sharepoint sites that have the locale specified in the context path.

**Example:**

https://mytest.sharepoint.com/en-us/MySubSite

I have set up a test SharePoint web application and I want to create a subsite that is prefaced by the locale just like they have.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The url syntax suggests the 'en-us'-part is the path name to the collection. By default (at least in O365) i would be 'sites' like this: https://mytest.sharepoint.com/sites/MySubSite

But in central administration/office 365 SharePoint administration it's possible to configure whatever you like instead of "sites".

Also technically speaking 'MySubSite' wouldn't be a subsite but rather an independent collection from https://mytest.sharepoint.com

My money is on this approach :)